# What is a better way to ask "until which grade is this school available"

Tags: sentence

Looking for school admissions for my kid and somehow the sound of this question puts me off. (I want to know till which grade does the school currently runs (offer classes) like 8, 9, 10, 12?)

I'm sure there is a better way out there to construct/rephrase this question. *Until which grade is this school available?*

Comment: "What grades do you cover?"

Comment: "What grades are taught in your school?"

Comment: What is the highest grade in this school?

Comment: Shouldn’t this information be available on the school’s website or advertising materials?  It seems unlikely that they’d not publish this and make you ask.

Comment: What grades does this school have?

Comment: @Jim We were visiting an exhibition where several old and new schools have put up their stalls.